# Using a variable to trigger a colour change using jQuery color.js

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the colour of an element (in this example a 100px x 100px  square called "block" from transparent to black when the variable trigger= 1. The code listed below works with a button. I have other javascript (that this code will be incorporated into that does work with trigger.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colourswap.css">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="_js/jquery.color.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="block">Hello!</div>
    <!--button id="go">Simple</button-->
    <script>
    var trigger = 1;
        (function(){
        if (trigger == 1) {
      jQuery("#block").animate({
          backgroundColor: "#000"
      }, 1500 );
      };
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So when does the variable change? Short of using an interval to check the variable there's no way to know when a variable changes, but you are probably the one changing it, so trigger the color change at the same time

Comment: exact, or use a timer to control the trigger variable or when the variable changes do change the color

Comment: adeno If I understand you correctly, the value if trigger is either 0 or 1 and is set in a PHP file and passed to javascript. Obviously the colour needs to change when the file is read. The variable is not changed in this script

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just use `.show()` or `.toggle()` if the block is transparent otherwise, e.g.

```
//say if you wanted the block to show when button is clicked
$("#go").click(function(){
    $("#block").toggle();
});
```

And then set the block's colour to black by default.

Comment: thanks minseong, but what about if there is no button, just the trigger variable?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, I have been unable to use my computer for a while. Anyway, you could just toggle the visibility instead of changing the variable couldn't you?